# How to view computer files from Android phone

Tags: android

Is there a way in Android Studio to see the files in a folder on a computer? For example, I am using the phone to control start/stop recording files and these files are then saved in a folder on a computer. Is there a way for the phone to see a list of the files that are in the folder?

My app currently keeps a log of every filename recorded, but if the app crashes for whatever reason or if there are files in the folder already I would like a way to know all files that are present

Answer (score 0):

[Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html?) provide the feature that allow developers to access to device storage.

Or you can use `adb pull <path-of-the-file>` to pull the needed files out of devices.